# Fifa 15 Pro Clubs in offline?

Tags: fifa-15

I want to improve my virtual pro.So i want play offline.But i cant play in offline career mode or something.Is there any way for that?Or is there any way for quickly improve my virtual pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Online and offline "pros" are separated. So you can't improve an online virtual pro in offline mode.

Comment: Well,How can i quickly improve my pro?

Comment: There is no real quick way. You can play, play and play more, level your account so you can buy virtual pro boosts in the in-game "store"

Comment: Thank you.By the way what are "in your 'only' career" in accomplishments?I thought it mean offline

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean

Comment: http://imgur.com/0u2pWlk I do not understand the meaning of the word here "only".because it does not increase the number of matches as i make matches.Still seems 0/92

Comment: I'm not sure, but i think you've to play either 92 matches with randoms or in a team online of course